# What Tee pseudo-muxer command line for multiple output ffmpeg works for output in mp4 and stream udp unicast?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, tee, muxer

I am using ffmpeg command line for getting multiple outputs with tee pseudo-muxer. Commands I have tried:

**Case 1-** To muxed Video (`video.h264`) with Audio (`audio.aac`) in mp4 and send mpegts to udp unicast address:

```
ffmpeg -i 'video.h264' -i "audio.aac" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -absf aac_adtstoasc -f tee -map 1:v -map 0:a "result.mp4|[f=mpegts]udp://127.0.0.1:2211"
```

**Output 1**: Resultant mp4 file has no audio and the udp stream when played is also having no audio.

**Case 2-** To muxed Video (`video.h26`4) with Audio (`audio.aac`) in mpegts file and send mpegts to udp unicast address:

```
ffmpeg -i 'video.h264' -i "audio.aac" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f tee -map 1:v -map 0:a "[f=mpefts]result.mpeg|[f=mpegts]udp://127.0.0.1:2211"
```

**Output 2**: Resultant mpegts file is fine and the udp stream when played is also having audio. NO ISSUE in this.

I have to do **Case 1** where i can mux aac and h264 and get two output one is mp4 file dump and second is stream mpegts udp unicast (like udp://127.0.0.1:2211). And both the output should have video+audio.

Can anybody tell me why in Case 1 the output file is not having audio?

Comment: If there's no typo in your commands, then your map assignments are reversed. It should be `-map 0:v -map 1:a`

Comment: I tried other - map options:  __Command 1 :__  
"ffmpeg -i 'video.h264' -i "audio.aac" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -absf aac_adtstoasc -f tee -map 0:v -map 1:a "result.mp4|[f=mpegts]udp://127.0.0.1:2211""  __Output1:__ AAC bitstream not in ADTS format.  __Command 2 :__  "ffmpeg -i 'video.h264' -i "audio.aac" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f tee -map 0:v -map 1:a "result.mp4|[f=mpegts]udp://127.0.0.1:2211" "  __Output:__ Malformed AAC bitstream detected: use the audio bitstream filter 'aac_adtstoasc ' to fix it. av_interleaved_write_frame(): Operation not permitted.

Comment: Can any one help me in doing Tee pseudo muxer by c++ code?